# Fill out the form

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

> I **filled out** the form that only required patients name and patients
>   room number

Is this sentence correct?

I understand that in American English people use **fill out** the form instead of **fill in** the form. But how can I say that the form demanded./required these details to enter...

Comment: To me, your sentence implies that the form you filled in had only 2 fields and it doesn't mention that those fields were required. Sure, we can assume both fields in a two-field form should be filled out.

Answer (score 2):

> But how can I say that the form demanded./required these details to enter...

A good word to use in this case is [**mandatory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandatory).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : required by a law or rule : OBLIGATORY
>   // the *mandatory* retirement age

So, in your sentence, you could say:

> I filled out the form with mandatory patient name and room number information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 'fill out' is standard idiom in American English and far more used in the US than in UK or other countries.
To fill out the form is to complete it. To fill in the form is to supply information as required

> It was obligatory to fill out the necessary fields in the form (like name and room number).